# What does "netstat -n -o" mean?

Tags: netstat, spyware, anti-spyware

When I type `netstat -n -o`, I get a lot of foreign addresses and my Internet Provider Customer Service is telling me that it means that I got spyware on my computer.

What that command really means?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of the `netstat` command is usually to show the *currently active connections* from or to your computer. This list includes *all* apps – the shown connections may be related to your web browsing, or games, or BitTorrent downloads, or indeed even to malware.

To know which is which you'd have to consider the number of connections, the addresses and ports they connect to, and of course the program making those connections.

On Windows, the `-o` option tells it to show a column with the process ID which created each connection. So for each connection, you can find the corresponding program in Task Manager's "Detail" tab.

The `-n` option tells netstat to always show IP addresses, instead of trying to translate them to names (which can be slow and often useless).

Comment: And 'Local' vs 'Foreign' address in TCP/IP simply means your computer vs any other computer anywhere -- not necessarily a different country. And anyone who tells you to be concerned about 'foreign' addresses, especially if you didn't contact them by a previously-vetted channel, is usually a fake scamming criminal impersonator.

Comment: @grawity is there any way to identify the malware from the list of addresses?